# Accurate BPM Detection on a music file C#

Tags: c#, signal-processing

I've been doing a lot of research on this and I'm still having trouble, so I'm hoping someone with a strong knowledge of Digital (Audio) Signal Processing can point me in the right direction.

I've been surprised at how hard it is to find a library that can perform accurate beat detection.  I know next to nothing about DSP and FFTs.  What I would really like is a library where I can simply say:

```
BPMDetect detector = new BPMDetect();
float bpm = detector.GetBpm(filename);
```

But apparently this is too much to ask for.  The closest I've gotten is by using the SoundTouch library, but I've recently discovered that the BPM detection there is very unreliable.  I know bpm detection isn't an exact science, but SoundTouch claimed that one of my music files was 170 BPM, while abyssmedia's BPM Counter program accurately puts it at 120 BPM.  So I know it's possible.  I'm more concerned with accuracy than speed.

So my question is: is there a C# library that can do this without having to know a lot about DSP?

Comment: have you looked at aubio.com

Comment: lol you sound like me Tevis. Did you find any good libraries?

Comment: not really anything yet so far, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do basic beat detection without resorting to FFTs. I've built beat detection algorithms that did this.

The basic idea is to take your audio signal and partition it into small buckets of time, say 10msec or so. For each bucket compute the RMS power: for each sample s[i] in the bucket, normalize to -1.0...1.0 and them compute the sum of s[i]**2.

Now you've got an array of power (= loudness) for little grains of time.

Next take the rate of change (derivative) from bucket to bucket: d[i] = s[i+1] - s[i].

The array of derivates tells you how fast the loudness is increasing from grain to grain. The faster the change, the more intense the beat is.

Here's where it gets a bit artful. You put a threshold on these d[i] values to decide which ones are sudden enough to constitute a beat. Then you do autocorrelation to see if they are steady and line up in a regular pattern.